# The selector "new-selector" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I need to change the selector name (selector: 'app-root') in app.component.ts to other name.

Let it be selector: 'new-selector'.

It shows,

Error: "The selector "new-selector" did not match any elements"

When the selector name changed, which all files are affected? How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change selector name of app.component.ts

then you need to change it in index.html

```
from  <app-root> </app-root>
to    <new-selector> </new-selector>
```

Comment: Yeah.. Issue closed

Answer (score 0):

Changes that has to be done are:

HTML:

```
<app-root> to <new-selector>
```

Component.ts:

```
@Component {
  selector: 'new-selector'    //change here from app-root to new-selector 
 }
```

Hope That Helped!!, If not please share a working example on stackblitz